# verify if cell is the same and build an excelfile

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have some measurements(as a dict) and a list with labels. Need to verify if labels are in my measurements and write it to an excelfile.

my output-excelfile need to look like this.

```
list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

measurement1 = {'A':1, 'B':1}
measurement2 = {'C':3, 'D':4}

#Output
                    'A'     'B'     'C'     'D'
measurement1         1       1       0       0
measurement2         0       0       1       1
```

I have no idea how to build the matrix with (0,1)
Hope you can help me.

**EDIT**

Finally i got a solution. At first i iterate over all measurements and wrote to dict measurements all missing labels. 
Than building a dataframe with ones and putting with 3 loops zeros in the dataframe to the msising positions with .loc

```
d = pd.DataFrame(1, index = measurements.keys(), columns = list1)
for y in measurements.keys():
    for z in measurements[y]:
        for x in list1:
            if x == z:
                d.loc[y,z] = 0
```

Maybe its possible to make it with only 2 loops.

Answer (score 2):

Use nested list comprehension with filtering for check membership in `list1` and last create `DataFrame` by constructor:

```
list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

measurement1 = {'A':1, 'B':1}
measurement2 = {'C':3, 'D':4}

L = [measurement1, measurement2]
d = [dict.fromkeys([y for y in x.keys() if y in list1], 1) for x in L]
df = pd.DataFrame(d).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  1  1  0  0
1  0  0  1  1
```

Comment: ty this looks really nice, but i need to change it a lil bit because i have big datas and i am loading the measurements in a loop. i have already written my missing labels to a dict. i will try to solve it an post my solution

Comment: i added my solution. Maybe i was to stupid to explain my problem :D

Comment: @credenco - what is `measurements` ?

Answer (score 1):

This should work, using only standard Python:

```
list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
measurement1 = {'A':1, 'B':1}
measurement2 = {'C':3, 'D':4}

measurements = [measurement1, measurement2]
headers = { h: i for i, h in enumerate(list1) }

matrix = []
for measurement in measurements:
    row = [0] * len(headers)
    for header in measurement.keys():
        row[headers[header]] = 1
    matrix.append(row)
```

For your example, the output will be:

```
matrix
=> [[1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list of the dictionaries ad create a dataframe then [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with the list and convert to bool by checking `notna`

```
pd.DataFrame([measurement1,measurement2]).reindex(columns=list1).notna().astype(int)
```

---

```
   A  B  C  D
0  1  1  0  0
1  0  0  1  1
```